# Open process and save specific images in related folder

Tags: python, image, crop

I'm looking for a way to open and crop several tiff images and then save the new croped images created in the same folder (related to my script folder).

My current code looks like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import os,platform

filespath = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'],"Desktop\Python\originalImagesfolder")

for file in os.listdir(filespath):
    if file.endswith(".tif"):
        im = Image.open(file)
        im.crop((3000, 6600, 3700, 6750)).save(file+"_crop.tif")
```

This script is returning me the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users...\Desktop\Python\script.py", line 22, in
>   
>       im = Image.open(file)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2219, in open
>       fp = builtins.open(fp, "rb") 
>   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Image1Name.tif'

'Image1Name.tif' is the first tif image I'm trying to process in the folder. I don't get how the script can give the file's name without being able to find it. Any Help?

PS: I have 2 days experience in python and codes generaly speaking. Sorry if the answer is obvious

**[EDIT/Update]**
After modifying my initial code thanks to vttran and ChrisGuest answers, turning then into this:

```
from PIL import Image
import os,platform

filespath = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'],"Desktop\Python\originalImagesfolder")

for file in os.listdir(filespath):
    if file.endswith(".tif"):
        filepath = os.path.join(filespath, file)
        im = Image.open(filepath)
        im.crop((3000, 6600, 3700, 6750)).save("crop"+file)
```

the script is returning me a new error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/.../Desktop/Python/script.py", line 11, in
>   
>       im.crop((3000, 6600, 3700, 6750)).save("crop"+file)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 986, in crop
>       self.load()
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 166, in load
>       self.load_prepare()
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 250, in
>   load_prepare
>       self.im = Image.core.new(self.mode, self.size) ValueError: unrecognized mode

A maybe-useful information, it's a Landsat8 image in GeoTiff format. The TIFF file therefore include geoposition, projection... informations. The script works perfectly fine if I first open and re-save them with a software like Photoshop (16int tiff format).

Comment: FileNotFoundError is thrown by Image.py. The file is found by the `os.listdir` call. But you provide the `filespath` there. You need to append the `filespath` to the Image.open() call like so `im = Image.open(os.path.join(filespath,file))`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The script is returning me now the error:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2215, in open
    raise ValueError("bad mode %r" % mode)
ValueError: bad mode 'Image1.TIF'. 
This doesn't look related to the file's format since the same functions used on the same Image in the script folder works perfectly fine...

Comment: somehow you're passing in "Image1.TIF" as the mode parameter. Which line in your own code is causing this exception? Please update your post with your new code and the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are search for the file names you use filespath to specify the directory.

But then when you open the file, you are only using the base filename.

So you could replace

```
im = Image.open(file)
```

with

```
filepath = os.path.join(filespath, file)
im = Image.open(filepath)
```

Also consider using the glob module, as you can do `glob.glob(r'path\*.tif)` .
It is also good practice to avoid using builtin functions like `file` as variable names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I had to add "path" to make it works: 'os.path.join'.

Comment: Apologies. You are correct. I have fixed this in my solution.

Comment: If that answer works for you, please click the arrow next to it to accept it.